# Where is the default Maven tomcat plugin configured?

Tags: maven, tomcat

In a Maven project I can use the tomcat plugin without adding it to the POM. So I can deploy and run my webapp for example like this:

```
mvn clean install tomcat:run
```

I know that it is using some default configuration, but my question is why Maven allows me to use this plugin even though I haven't configured it? It also isn't in the super POM. So I have no idea where it's configuration comes from. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven has some conventions about it, even if you do not configure anything in the project POM or in your *settings.xml*.
When you invoke a plugin that way in the command line, Maven tries to find the plugin by adding one of the following groupId's:

- org.apache.maven.plugins
- org.codehaus.mojo

For the artifactId, it also tries to complete the "prefix" you specify (here *tomcat*) with one of these:

- **maven-${prefix}-plugin**: (convetion for official plugins) -> *maven-tomcat-plugin*
- **${prefix}-maven-plugin**: (convention for 3rd party plugins) -> *tomcat-maven-plugin*

And for the version, it just tries to get the latest available.

In your particular case, there is a match for the defaults: *org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1* (or any other available version).

[A bit more detail here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html) about the mechanics, and how you can also use these conventions for your own groupId's.